# JS Revealing module pattern: Params that shouldn't be used by usercode

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture, revealing-module-pattern

I have a module written structured with the revealing module pattern. This contains a sub-module that kind of works as an overload. A few functions of the main module have parameters that shouldn't be used with usercode - only via the submodule. How can I access the params from the submodule but make them unavailable for "external usercode"?
Should I make another layer for this?

```
var someNamespace = someNamespace || {};

someNamespace.someModule = (function () {

    // _customSiteUrl, _customToken shouldn't be available via usercode
    function create(listName, data, _customSiteUrl, _customToken) {
        ...
    }
    var XS = (function () {
        return {
            createXS: function (siteUrl, listName, data) {
                ...
                create(listName, data, siteUrl, token);
            }
        }
    })();

    return {
        create: create,
        XS: XS,
        ...
    }
})();

someNamespace.someModule.create("hi", {}, "https://...", "someHash"); //Should not be possible!!
someNamespace.someModule.create("hi", {}); //Should be used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another "layer" in your `.someModule`with the any user-inaccessible variables being declared locally, and change the `create:` property of your return to this layer, instead of the base function.

You have to remember, you can create as many "overloads" as you like, but they will all retain the same parameters that you declare in the "overload" you're returning. What you pass inside that overload to the base function (`create`) is entirely up to you and entirely private.

```
someNamespace.someModule = (function () {

    // _customSiteUrl, _customToken shouldn't be available via usercode
    function create(listName, data, _customSiteUrl, _customToken) {
        ...
    }

    function userAccessibleCreate () {
        return create(parameters, you, want);
    };
    var XS = (function () {
        return {
            createXS: function (siteUrl, listName, data) {
                ...
                create(listName, data, siteUrl, token);
            }
        }
    })();

    return {
        create: userAccessibleCreate,
        XS: XS,
        ...
    }
})();
```

Now, the user can only only do `someNamespace.someModule.create("hi", {});`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want to remove the parameters `_customSiteUrl` etc from the public facing create function, you can use something like:

```
return {
    create: function( listName, data ) {
        return create( listName, data, _customSiteUrl, _customToken );
    }, 
    XS: XS,
    ...
};
```

This assumes that `_customSiteUrl` and `_customToken` are defined in the scope of the submodule. You basically just have the public API call the private API with the extra parameters.

You could use a curry or partial application function for this as well, but i'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Well you didn't understand what I meant. See Crowes' answer.
Thanks for your time though.

Comment: It's essentially the same thing coded differently. Crowes also has to add the public parameters (parameters, you, want) to the `userAccessibleCreate` function, since as written it doesn't accept any named parameters without using arguments object.